# Android ListView Item Selector appear for the whole list

Tags: android, list, listview, adapter

i want to change the default selection color of my listview items in my list as followed:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" 
        android:state_pressed="false"
        android:drawable="@color/Blue" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" 
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@color/Black" />
   <item android:drawable="@color/White" />
</selector>
```

then i set the selecotor to my list using

```
android:listSelector="@drawable/list_item_selector"
```

the problem is when i want to set the selector as shown above, the selection is not applied to the single item but to the whole list.

can anybody help me please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting this as background to individual item in your list.